# Not able to iterate ItemList from Transaction class

Tags: java

This is my `Item` class:

```
public class Item {

 private String id;
 private int count;
 private String  name;

public int getcount() {
   return this.count;
}

public Item(String name) {
     this.name=name;
     this.id = "";

 }

public Item(String id, String name) {
   this.name=name;
   this.id=id;
 }

public Item(int count) {
    this.count=count;
}

public String getItemName() {
    return this.name;
}

public String getItemId() {
    return this.id;
}

public Item returnItems(ItemList itemset) {
    Item item=null;
    return item;
  }
}
```

This is my `ItemList` class which will contain a `List` of `items`:

```
public  class ItemList implements Iterable<Item>  {

  private List<Item> hold=new ArrayList<Item>();



  ItemList(Item item) {
    this.hold.add(item);
  }

  ItemList() {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
  }


  public List<Item> getItemSet() {
    return this.hold;
  }


  public void addItems(Item item) {
    this.hold.add(item);
  }


  @Override
  public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
    Iterator<Item> item = hold.iterator();
    return item;
  }
}
```

This is the `Transaction` class:

```
public class Transaction implements Iterable {

 private List<ItemList> trans=new ArrayList<ItemList>();

 public List<Item> getUniqueItems() {

    Database d = new Database();
    List<Item> unique = new ArrayList<Item>();

    String query="Select id,name from item";
    ResultSet rs = d.sendQuery(query);
    try {
        while(rs.next()) {
           // System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"\t"+rs.getString(2));
            unique.add(new Item(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2)));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }
    return unique;
}

public ItemList getUniqueItem() {
     ResultSet rs;
     Database d=new Database();
     ItemList unique=new ItemList();
      String query="Select id,name from item";
      rs=d.sendQuery(query);
        try{
        while(rs.next())
         {
           //System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"\t"+rs.getString(2));
           Item item=new Item(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2));
           unique.addItems(item);
    }

    } catch(Exception e) {
       System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }

    return unique;
}


public void addTransaction(ItemList itemList) {
     this.trans.add(itemList);
}

public List<ItemList> getTransaction() {
     return this.trans;
}

@Override
public Iterator<ItemList> iterator() {
    Iterator<ItemList> itemList = trans.iterator();
    return itemList;
}

public int countItems(ItemList itemList) {
      ResultSet rs;
      Database d=new Database();
      String query="";
      int count=0;
      for(Item i:itemList)
     {
       System.out.println(i);
       String id=i.getItemId();
        System.out.print(id+"\t");
        query="SELECT count(*) FROM `item_transaction` where item_id="+id;
          rs=d.sendQuery(query);
          try{
           while(rs.next())
          {
              System.out.print(rs.getString(1));
              count=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));
              System.out.print(count+"\t");
          }

          }catch(Exception e){}
   }

      return count;
 }

 }
```

And this is my `main` class:

```
public class Ap {

public static void main(String args[])
{
   Transaction t=new Transaction();
    Transaction Ci=new Transaction();
   Transaction Li=new Transaction();

    List<Item> list = t.getUniqueItems();
    for(Item i:list)
    {
        ItemList itemList=new ItemList(i);
        Ci.addTransaction(itemList);
    }

}
```

After adding `itemList` to `Transaction`, I want to iterate over `Ci` and pass `itemList` to the `countItems` method in the `Transaction` class.

I tried:

```
for(ItemList list:Ci) {
    int x=t.countItems(list);
}
```

But am getting:

```
found  java.lang.Object
      Required ItemList
```

Or do I have to get the `List<ItemList>` from the `Transaction` class and then iterate?

Comment: Can you reduce the amount of code to just the relevant bits? With all these classes it is quite difficult to tell what is being asked here. And people appreciate it when they can see that you've made an effort to ask a good question.

Comment: Edit your code, its a real mess. And respect naming conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make

```
 class Transaction implements Iterable<ItemList>
```

As it is you are saying that its Iterable of plain Objects.